# Arquillian- Test class not found as the war is undeployed

Tags: jboss, ejb, wildfly, jboss-arquillian, shrinkwrap

I'm trying to run my unit testing with Arquillian. I configured it with Maven having both Wildfly managed and remote servers. After running the test the server starts and deploys my war. Immediately after deploying it undeploys and removes the war resluting in ClassNotFound exception, I'm providing below the stacktrace:

> 19:46:23,101 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository]
> (management-handler-thread - 3) JBAS014900: **Content added at location
> /home/remotedev/QSDev2/app-qs/target/wildfly-8.2.1.Final/standalone/data/content/29/401e4f9cd9cff55c2a0cd817a4163817b4d7c4/content**
> 19:46:23,172 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service
> thread 1-2) JBAS015876: **Starting deployment of "testwar.war"
> (runtime-name: "testwar.war")** 19:46:25,769 WARN
>  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS016012:
> Deployment deployment "testwar.war" contains CDI annotations but no
> bean archive was found (no beans.xml or class with bean defining
> annotations). 19:46:26,590 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC
> service thread 1-2) JBAS017534: **Registered web context: /testwar**
> 19:46:26,736 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread -
> 3) JBAS018559: **Deployed "testwar.war"** (runtime-name : "testwar.war")
> 2021-03-23 19:46:28 DEBUG nio:429 - Started channel thread 'Remoting
> "endpoint" I/O-1', selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@381d206c
> 2021-03-23 19:46:28 DEBUG VersionedConectionFactory:173 - Available
> version (Versions  0x00 0x01) 2021-03-23 19:46:28 DEBUG
> VersionedConectionFactory:179 - Calling a stable server 2021-03-23
> 19:46:28 DEBUG VersionedConectionFactory:131 - Selecting version 0x00
> to receive full version list. 2021-03-23 19:46:28 DEBUG
> VersionedConectionFactory:173 - Available version (Versions  0x01
> 0x02) 2021-03-23 19:46:28 DEBUG VersionedConectionFactory:179 -
> Calling a stable server 2021-03-23 19:46:28 DEBUG
> VersionedConectionFactory:194 - Server version 2.0.0.Final
> 19:46:29,576 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service
> thread 1-2) JBAS017535: **Unregistered web context: /testwar**
> 19:46:29,678 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version]
> (MSC service thread 1-1) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.3.Final
> 19:46:30,504 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service
> thread 1-1) JBAS015877: **Stopped deployment testwar.war (runtime-name:
> testwar.war)** in 945ms 19:46:30,543 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository]
> (management-handler-thread - 3) J**BAS014901: Content removed from
> location
> /home/remotedev/QSDev2/app-qs/target/wildfly-8.2.1.Final/standalone/data/content/29/401e4f9cd9cff55c2a0cd817a4163817b4d7c4/content**
> 19:46:30,551 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread -
> 3) JBAS018558: Undeployed "testwar.war" (runtime-name: "testwar.war")
> Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 24.115
> sec <<< FAILURE!
> testSaveLeaveRequest(com.maestro.application.authentication.util.PasswordStrengthTest)
>  Time elapsed: 0.343 sec  <<< ERROR! java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> com.maestro.application.authentication.util.PasswordStrengthTest from
> [Module "deployment.testwar.war:main" from Service Module Loader]

I can't figure out why it's undeploying the war after deploying. Could anyone help me figure out the problem? (Posted at Arquillian forum, no reply yet http://discuss.arquillian.org/t/test-class-not-found-as-the-war-is-undeployed/656). Thanks

--Rashed

Latest update- 04-07-2021

Now getting following exception, CNFE is gone:

> Caused by: java.lang.Exception: {
> "JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "test.war"
> Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011047: Component class com.maestro.ejb.dao.EntityManagerProvider for component LeaveRequestLocalHome has errors:
> JBAS011440: Can't find a persistence unit named optimalOneDefaultPersistenceUnit in deployment "test.war""},
> "JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".beanmanager]"]
> }

The test code looks like below:

```
    @RunWith(Arquillian.class)
    public class PasswordStrengthTest { 
    @Deployment
    public static JavaArchive createDeployment() {
        return ShrinkWrap
                .create(JavaArchive.class)
                .addClasses(LeaveRequestLocal.class,
                        LeaveRequestLocalHome.class, LeaveRequestInfo.class,
                        LeaveRequestManagerBean.class,
                        LeaveRequestController.class, LeaveRequestBean.class,
                        EntityManagerProvider.class, JpaEntity.class,
                        MaestroEntityBean.class, MaestroValueObject.class,
                        JpaDaoBean.class, GenericDao.class,
                        SearchManagerException.class, MaestroException.class,
                        NoSuchLeaveRequestException.class,
                        MaestroExceptionDetails.class,
                        MaestroRuntimeException.class, TableParameters.class,
                        SearchParameters.class, PagedList.class)                        
                .addAsManifestResource("META-INF/persistence.xml")
                .addAsResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");   

    }

    @Inject
    private LeaveRequestManagerBean leaveRequestManagerBean;

    @Inject
    private LeaveRequestLocalHome leaveRequestLocalHome;

    @Inject
    private LeaveRequestController leaveRequestController;

    @Test   
    public void testSaveLeaveRequest() throws Exception {       
        String name = "abc";
        String requestDetails = "req1";
        leaveRequestManagerBean = (LeaveRequestManagerBean) EJBUtil
                .getLocalEJBManager("LeaveRequestManager");
        LeaveRequestInfo leaveReuestInfo = leaveRequestManagerBean.add();

        leaveReuestInfo.setName(name);
        leaveReuestInfo.setRequestDetails(requestDetails);      

        leaveRequestManagerBean.update(leaveReuestInfo);        
        
    }   
  }
```

And the POM looks like below:

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.quickschools</groupId>
    <artifactId>app-qs</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>app-qs</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <version.org.jboss.arquillian>1.1.5.Final</version.org.jboss.arquillian>
        <version.org.wildfly>8.2.1.Final</version.org.wildfly>
        <version.junit>4.11</version.junit>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <property>
                            <name>java.util.logging.config.file</name>
                            <value>log4j.properties</value>
                        </property>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>

            <!-- Arquillian BOM (Bill Of Materials). -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.5.Final</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>

            <!-- JUnit regression testing framework. -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.11</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <profiles>

        <!-- Arquillian WildFly managed profile -->
        <profile>
            <id>arq-wildfly-managed</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
                    <version>${version.org.wildfly}</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>sun.jdk</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jconsole</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <testResources>
                    <testResource>
                        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                    </testResource>
                </testResources>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>unpack</id>
                                <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>unpack</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <artifactItems>
                                        <artifactItem>
                                            <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                                            <artifactId>wildfly-dist</artifactId>
                                            <version>${version.org.wildfly}</version>
                                            <type>zip</type>
                                            <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                                        </artifactItem>
                                    </artifactItems>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <!-- Arquillian WildFly remote profile -->
        <profile>
            <id>arq-widlfly-remote</id>
            <!-- <activation> <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault> </activation> -->
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
                    <version>${version.org.wildfly}</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>sun.jdk</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jconsole</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>

    </profiles>



    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.quickschools</groupId>
            <artifactId>sms-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>/home/remotedev/mnt/sms2/build/ear/01sms.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.quickschools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gengo</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>/home/remotedev/ProgramFiles/wildfly-12.0.0.Final/modules/com/quickschools/libs/main/gengo.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- for arqillian -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>ejb-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ejb-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency> <!-- for arqillian -->
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.5.Final</version>
            <!-- <version>1.6.0.Final</version> -->
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>



        

        

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>   
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Thanks

**Update 09-04-2021**
Changed accordingly, now the delpoyment code looks like below:

```
 return ShrinkWrap
                .create(JavaArchive.class)
                .addClasses(LeaveRequestLocal.class,
                        LeaveRequestLocalHome.class, LeaveRequestInfo.class,
                        LeaveRequestManagerBean.class,
                        LeaveRequestController.class, LeaveRequestBean.class,
                        EntityManagerProvider.class, JpaEntity.class,
                        MaestroEntityBean.class, MaestroValueObject.class,
                        JpaDaoBean.class, GenericDao.class,
                        SearchManagerException.class, MaestroException.class,
                        NoSuchLeaveRequestException.class,
                        MaestroExceptionDetails.class,
                        MaestroRuntimeException.class, TableParameters.class,
                        SearchParameters.class, PagedList.class)
                .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml")
                .addAsManifestResource("persistence.xml");
```

After deleting META-INF from persistence.xml path, it can't find it now, showing exception as follows:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: persistence.xml doesn't exist or can't be accessed
> at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:43)
> at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.container.ContainerBase.fileFromResource(ContainerBase.java:1966)
> at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.container.ContainerBase.addAsManifestResource(ContainerBase.java:683)

I tried with keeping beans.xml and presistence.xml at both /resources/META-INF and /test/resources/META-INF, which path is correct? Thanks

Comment: What does the test code look like? You're getting a CNFE which looks to be the problem.

Comment: Sorry for being late. CNFE is gone now, please see above, I updated post with current exception and also the test code. Thanks

Comment: Your `beans.xml` needs to be in the `META-INF` directory. When creating your deployment use `.addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");`. Also remove the `META-INF` from the other manifest resource entry.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input, I tried this. Please see my update above starting with Update 09-04-2021. Thanks

Comment: Give your path I'd assume it should be in `test/resources`.

Comment: Yes, it's in test/resources, thanks